# Linking to shared boost library giving headaches

Tags: c++, boost, shared-libraries, boost-program-options

I have an issue which sounds annoyingly simple, but I feel I've tried everything to resolve it and I'm out of ideas.

I have a program I wrote which uses boost/program_options.hpp using the include statement

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
```

This program works on my laptop and now I am trying to put it onto a server where I don't have sudo privileges. On my laptop, where the whole thing works I have boost versions 1.56 and 1.58 and on the server I found 1.53.0. I didn't install or build this though.

The shared library file that exists on the server is:
/usr/lib64/libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0

Running ldd on that gives me the output:

```
 ldd /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc54a63000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc0dcad8000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc0dc7d5000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc0dc5bf000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc0dc1fe000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc0dd071000)
```

Which I assume means it's found all its dependencies.

I have made a symbolic link to my home directory to create a libboost_program_options.so link, which I guess means the -lboost_program_options linker flag should work.

The way I compile is by:

```
g++ -L/home/homeDir code.cpp -o code.o -std=c++11 -Wall -lboost_program_options
```

And all I get is:

```
fatal error: boost/program_options.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "boost/program_options.hpp"
                                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

I've tried this with quotes and <>, and without "boost/" etc, but I always get the same complaint. I assume this means that it finds the library as there is no complaint about the -lboost_program_options flag?

While it works on my machine, I may not be using the shared program options library at all. On my laptop I have both a static version of libboost_program_options in my library path which it may be using, and the program_options.hpp header outside of a library which may be in my include path. I feel like I should be able to use the shared library that's on the server and not annoy the server admin for the 5th time (things work really slowly with these things here).

I'm sorry if this is my oversight. I'm fairly new to boost, but I feel like I've tried everything to resolve this myself at the moment.

I'd be happy with any suggestions as to how I could change this... or if I'm just being a bit stupid with using shared libraries.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
After more research I feel like I'm just getting confused between static and shared libraries. I'm trying to link a shared library at compile time, which I guess doesn't make sense. Also including the header file of something which should not be linked at compile time makes little sense. My code is clearly designed for the static library.

Comment: `g++ -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib64 -lboost_program_options -std=c++11  ...`

Comment: It is possible that your server does not have `program_options.hpp`, which should be in some package named like boost_program_options_**devel**.

Comment: yeah, that's my problem. I thought I could get by without it, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I have now just linked to a static version of program options on my laptop and am using the executable on the server. It's working so far.. but I feel like I should be able to get this to compile on the server as well. I've now downloaded the header files and it decided it can't find libboost_program_options.so although i've created a symbolic link into the same directory I'm running from... fun ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is produced by the pre-compiler which does not find the Boost header file (as it says in the error message). You need to set the correct include path (`-I...`) where the Boost library header files are found, obviously they are not under `/usr/include`.

Path to the Boost libraries (`-L...`) must be specified accordingly.

Finally: If you are linking against the Boost shared libraries on your system, then you should use the same version of Boost as installed on the server. Otherwise, link against the static libraries, this may make you executable larger, but it will run on any server, regardless of the Boost version installed there (even none).

Comment: So to clarify, to use boost program options I need both the header file somewhere and the shared library object? I thought the shared library object might contain the header file and the code for the functions I want to call. I haven't used shared libraries before clearly...

I'm recompiling when I switch to the server, but it might be a good idea to just link to the static library on my system and use the executable on the server. That might save a lot of pain.

Comment: Thanks, I just downloaded the header files and now I have an error I can work with a bit better. -lboost_program_options cannot be found. Strange to be happy about an error. But at least I've seen this before somewhere online.

Comment: To compile, you need both the header file and the shared library. To run the program, you only need the shared library. Actually, you only need the shared library if really symbols from the shared library are needed, a lot of stuff in the Boost libraries is in the headers only and therefore directly compiled into your executable.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am using program_options, which is compiled as well. So I need the shared library in the end. Now dealing with why it can't find it... but I've solved my initial problem. And I have a workaround with static linking and shipping over the executable onto the server. So I'm fairly happy... learned a lot and got something that works :).

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt install libboost-program-options-dev